# Convert SQL Query in LINQ and Select Count

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have 2 SQL query i have try to convert using linqer but no result. The Query like this :

```
select distinct a.DOCID,
(select dcrea from mstdocs where DOCID = a.docid and vtype = 'table') DOC_DATE,
(select dcrea from mstdocs where DOCID= a.docid and vtype = 'read' and VTAID = '2') Read_DATE
from mstdocs a, mstdocstats b
where a.docid = b.docid
and a.vtaid = '2'
and a.vtype = 'read'
and DATEPART(mm,a.DCREA)  = '06'
and DATEPART(yyyy,a.DCREA) = '2016'
and a.docid in 
(
select distinct a.docid 
from mstdocs a, mstdocstats b
where a.docid = b.docid
and a.vtype = 'table'
and DATEPART(mm,a.DCREA)  = '06'
and DATEPART(yyyy,a.DCREA) = '2016'
)


select distinct a.docid
from mstdocs a, mstdocstats b
where a.docid = b.docid
and (select count(*) from mstdocs docs where docs.DOCID = a.docid and docs.vtaid = '2') = 1
```

I have try convert the first query separate into two parts

- var a = (from b in mstdocstats 
                           join a in mstdocs on a.docid equals b.docid 
                           where a.vtype.Equals("table")
                           && a.DCREA.Month == '06' && a.DCREA.Year == '2016'
                           select a.docid).Distinct().ToList();
- var b = (from b in mstdocstats
                                join a in mstdocs on a.docid equals b.docid 
                                where a.Contains(a.docid) 
                                select new {
                                 docid = a.docid,
                               DOC_DATE = (from mstdoc in mstdocs where a.docid == mstdoc.docid && mstdoc.vtype == "table" select
  mstdoc.DCREA),
                                 Read_DATE = (from mstdoc in mstdocs where a.docid == mstdoc.docid && mstdoc.vtype == "read"  &&
  mstdoc.vtaid == "2" select mstdoc.DCREA)}).ToList();

but becomes error, can anybody tell me where is the mistakes?

thanks for any answers...

Answer (score 0):

I supposed that `DCREA` is `Datetime`.. the first query gets initially the subset of `mstdocs` that falls in the june 2016 date interval, and from this gets the read subset of "read" `mstdocs`...

```
var qry_1 = (from a in (
                from a in mstdocs
                join b in mstdocstats on a.docid equals b.docid 
                where a.DCREA.Month == 6 && a.DCREA.Year == 2016
                select a
            )join b in mstdocstats on a.docid equals b.docid 
             where a.vtaid == "2" && a.vtype == "read" 
             select new {
                       DOCID = a.Name,
                       Read_DATE = a.DCREA,
                       DOC_DATE = (from mstdoc in mstdocs where a.docid == mstdoc.docid && mstdoc.vtype == "table" select mstdoc.DCREA)
                     }
            ).Distinct().ToList();




var qry_2 = (from a in 
             (from a in mstdocs
              where a.vtaid == "2"
              group a by a.docid into GroupMstdocs
              where GroupMstdocs.Count() == 1
              select new { docid = GroupMstdocs.Key }
             ) join b in mstdocstats on a.docid equals b.docid
               select a.docid
            ).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: yes field dcrea is datetime, but i compile that query and the result is Identifier expected; 'in' is a keyword, if i wantto store that query into list, can i give tolist() after distinct()?

Comment: Absolutely yes.. you can add toList () at the  of The querys

Comment: but i have no results , i don't why that becomes error :(

Comment: What query of two get error ? Do your sql queries get results?

Comment: sorry, i have  a little mistakes, the result query is right but for read date i get errors, if i not using read_date and doc_date the query results okay..so now i separate for results one by one, but the problems now for get read_date i have error " Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<datetime>", can you help me with this errors? thanks :)

Comment: You should replace literals with variables.. instead, I find that your new issue it is quite strange, because you are getting in the first query a set of data composed by an id and two dates, while the second get only an id. So, I guess, where does came from that List<DateTime>?

Comment: Hey @NETDev, if I answered at your question it will be gladed a confirmation. Thank you